# Why is onCreate called twice but no onDestroy called between two onCreate in my Activity?

Tags: android

My team wrote a complex LBS/chat App, there is a MainActivity as main displaying activity. 
When this MainActivity started, "onCreate" is called the first time.
when I switch to other several Apps and go back to my App's MainActivity, "onCreate" is called second time.
But "onDestroy" of MainActivity has never been called.

Some pointers(Singleton/Global, not belong to any activity) will be "auto" set to null out of my control, it causes my app problem.

Does some module/class hold a reference to MainActivity or some other reasons?

I need help -_-!

Thanks to all guys who can give me some tips.

Thanks!

Comment: when calling after screen light off and on again or when like if u pass any intent in other activity then only one time it will call on create method and after than if activity resume then again on resume call dear

Answer (score 2):

OnCreate is call only once in activity circle life.
If your application was in background and return to foreground, the only reason that on create call again is because OS kill this activity.
you can save data with onSaveInstanceState().

Comment: I reviewed the lifecircle of Activity on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

I found something I had always wrong understand. App will be killed when memory is low, and onDestroy of Activity will not be called at this time, am I right?

Thanks

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html . -" Because onPause() is the first of the three, once the activity is created, onPause() is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be called. "

Comment: I want to stop one of my Service and uninit my ImageCache(do some uninit stuff such as disc flush/close operation) when my App is killed. Where is the better place for me to put my code?
Thanks!

Comment: If your application written according to programming method that all activity extend from main activity. you do it onPause() on main activity, if not i dont know. maybe is reciever or handler that can catch this case

Answer (score 0):

when you start activity this functions be called: `onCreate()` , `onStart()` , `onResume()` and when you going to another activity, `onPause()` called.

If you want to call `onDestroy()` to your app you must call `this.finish();` but, when you call `this.finish()` you must handle `onBackPress()` in your app.

I hope this useful to you